# Dynamic Alert View Text Body

Tags: iphone, sdk, uikit, uialertview

Can you edit the contents of an UIAlertView once it has been shown? I would like to be able to update the text in it without having to dismiss and show a new one every time.

Thanks in advance,

Jonathan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a UIAlertView delegate called didPresentAlertView:. It is fired once the UIAlertView is presented on the view. Inside there you can set any of its properties. Here is an example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"my message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
  [alert setDelegate:self];
  [alert show];
  [alert release];
}

- (void)didPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
  [alertView setTitle:@"My new title"];
  [alertView setMessage:@"My new message"];
}
```

Comment: This will allow you to change it once since didPresentAlertView is only called once after the alert is shown.

Comment: I realise this is an old thread but is there a way to delay the time it takes to present the second title and text, it happens so quick user doesn't get chance to read the first set of text in the AV

Answer (score 0):

Declare your `UIAlertView` in the `.h` , initiate it once (maybe in the `viewDidLoad`) . Show it only when it is first needed and than try changing its contents when you need to with:

```
  [alertView setTitle:@"new title"];
  [alertView setMessage:@"new message"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through [this](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/open-source/ios-open-source-heads-up-display-with-mbprogresshud.html) . I guess the MBProgressHUD library's mode switching display will suit your requirements better than messing up with alert views. That particular mode/component in the library shows multiple messages sequentially and you also have the provision to set timers for each message in the sequence.